# What is wrong with this input?

Tags: plotting, functions, parameters

I've followed the examples from the introduction to mathematica for math students:
https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/more-plots-in-2d/

```
xdt[x_, y_] := (sigma + 3) x + 4 y
ydt[x_, y_] := -(9/4) x + (sigma - 3) y
sigma := {-1, 0, 1}
StreamPlot[{xdt[x, y], ydt[x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

I execute each row one after the other by pressing shift+enter, and when I get to the last row only an empty plot-window shows up.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Welcome.  Your code works with `sigma = 1` and with `sigma = 0` and with `sigma = -1`.  What were you trying to obtain ?  Did you want 3 separate plots, one for each value of `sigma` ?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. And yes, three plots is what I'm going for, is there a way to make mathematica generate the plots sequentially?

Comment: Then remove the statement: `sigma := {-1, 0, 1}` and change the next one as follows: `Row[Table[
  StreamPlot[{xdt[x, y], ydt[x, y]}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
    10}], {sigma, {-1, 0, 1}}]]`